# Ultra realistic excrement material needed

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, shaders

Hey I need a very realistic poop material for cycles, I already have the cracks and shape, but I need a material with the correct look. I'm looking for something like this:

[image: https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/7/f/1/7f10f079677f1f640c1cc89e2a4219382b230bbb.jpg]

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you showed is not only a material, it's a heavy subdivided geometry with possible displacement applied to it.

[image]

1 - This looks like a separate geometry. Not part of the material aspect.

2 - This is part of the material, a bump or normal map.

My best point for you to go is sculpting, it will reproduce a organic model and you can easily reproduce these bumps you see.

For the material aspect, if you want to go for realism, Principled BSDF is great to simulate real gloss and light information.

I tried a simple material to show you what I mean:
[image]

You can see that with some adjustments you can achieve your goal, but then again, this is a heavily detailed object, it is not just a material.