# How to create an embossed/low relief texture?

Tags: modeling, texturing, modifiers

I would like to create realistic skin/organs by applying slight low-relief or embossed effect to a mesh surface as in this example, maybe from a grayscale image as reference (Note: the surface has a 3d texture and not just a standard flat image mapped over it.)
Thanks for any Inputs!
[image]

Comment: you can try playing with noise texture and bump nodes

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28942/methods-of-applying-bumpiness-to-materials/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116189/ultra-realistic-excrement-material-needed/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-do-i-make-a-normal-displacement-map-when-all-i-have-is-a-photo/

Comment: Thank you all for the useful links, i couldnt find the right keywords. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14351/what-is-the-difference-between-the-displace-socket-and-a-bump-map this is helpful too for people who look for the same thing